# Use Models / Controllers from a sub directory in new project

Tags: php, laravel

So I've been asked to create a new project in Laravel (5.4). The project will need to load in a "platform" which is also built in Laravel 5.4 and contains already written controllers and models.

I am currently autoloading the platform in composer as so :

```
"psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Frontend\\": "app/Modules/Frontend/",
            "Admin\\": "app/Modules/Admin/",
            "Platform\\": "../platform/Modules/"
        }
```

I have a routes file with the following in it :

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Then inside of my HomeController, I'm trying to load the platforms' HomeController.

```
use Platform\Modules\Frontend\Controllers\HomeController as HC;
```

I am then presented with the error

> Class 'Platform\Modules\Frontend\Controllers\HomeController' not found

Is this at all possible to do, wise to do? I'm open to any form of suggestions.

Comment: I guess it should be `Platform\Frontend\Controllers\HomeController` because you have already mentioned it as "../platform/Modules/" where modules is included

Comment: What's the namespace in HomeController file from platform project?

Comment: @parse

The namespace in that file is : `App\Modules\Frontend\Controllers;`

Comment: About if it's wise or not, it depends, if it's a small project then it's ok but if it's a large project that have more devs involved, then I won't suggest that approach.

Comment: It's a small project, it's mostly a reskin of what the existing platform is doing. Don't want to keep the same routes to prevent duplicate seo content issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to mimic your situation in 2 PHP hello world projects.

The problem here is that your 2 projects are using the same namespace `App` and when you try to autoload the 2nd project into the namespace `Platform`, you get `Class not found` error. This is because your PSR-4 namespace for `Platform` doesn't correspond the namespace in your 2nd project.

`App\Modules\Frontend\Controllers` is never `Platform\Modules\Frontend\Controllers`. Those are totally 2 different namespaces.

Hopefully, there's a solution for this by providing an array of paths to the common namespace in both projects.

```json
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": ["app/", "../platform/Modules/"],
            "Frontend\\": "app/Modules/Frontend/",
            "Admin\\": "app/Modules/Admin/"
        }
```

In your HomeController, load your controller like this:

```php
use App\Modules\Frontend\Controllers as HC;
```

Always double check running the command below if you get `Class not found error`:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Awesome @parse can you confirm what needs to be set in the "main / platform" projects composer file? When doing a dump-autoload on the "child" project, I can see some PSR mappings coming in from the packages that are loaded on the platform, so seems to be a step in the right direction. Just the platform to ammend, I think?

Comment: You should update your platform project composer file.